# details in the proof of Arithmetic–Geometric Means Inequality

Tags: real-analysis

in the book Problems in Real Analysis, it shows the proof of Arithmetic–Geometric Means Inequality:
$\tfrac{a_1+a_2+...+a_n}{n}>=\sqrt[n]{a_1a_2a_3...a_n}$, and then the author saies that relpace $a_k$ with $a_k\sqrt[n]{a_1a_2a_3...a_n}$, we have $a_1...a_n$=1, and it is enough to prove that $a_1+a_2+..+a_n>=n$. I just cannot understand the logic behind this. The author seems add a condition that $a_1...a_n=1$,why can we simplify the proof by this replacement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a rather roundabout way of describing the simple steps:

$$\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n a_k}{n} \geq \left ( \prod_{k=1}^n a_k \right )^{1/n} \\
\Leftrightarrow \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n a_k}{\left ( \prod_{j=1}^n a_k \right )^{1/n}} \geq n \\
\Leftrightarrow \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{a_k}{\left ( \prod_{j=1}^n a_j \right )^{1/n}} \geq n$$

which reduces the problem to showing that $\prod_{k=1}^n b_k=1$ implies $\sum_{k=1}^n b_k \geq n$ (since $\prod_{k=1}^n \frac{a_k}{\left ( \prod_{j=1}^n a_j \right )^{1/n}}=1$).